# Button action evaluation

Tags: evaluation, hold, button

An example of the problem I am encountering:

```
choices = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
buttons = {};
callMe[n_] := Module[{}, MessageDialog[choices[n]]];
test[] := Module[{},
   buttons = {};
   Scan[AppendTo[buttons, Button[#, callMe[Length@buttons + 1]]] &, choices];
   Return@buttons;
];
test[]
```

The call to test displays a list of buttons. When I click on one of these,
I want the 'n_' argument to 'callMe' to contain the index into 'choices' from which that button got its caption.  But this is not what happens.  n_ is always equal to 6 (the last value of 'Length@buttons+1'), no matter which button is clicked.  I've tried various combinations of ReleaseHold, Evaluate, etc.  This is most likely quite simple, but I can't get anything to work.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Button is HoldRest so you need to inject Length@buttons there. With[{l=Length...}, Button...]

Comment: Of course that works, and I think you've answered a nearly identical question for me in the past. Thanks Kuba, for your help and your patience.

Comment: @M.Robinson Your question goes basically under label "simple mistake". However, `Attributes` of functions lead more than often to unexpected behavior. Would you go ahead and post an answer to your question?

Comment: @M.Robinson I could not find the answer you've mentioned even though I remember it too :p Linked topics should cover that problem, let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @halirutan -- for this example (sorry, don't know how to format messages):

    choices = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    buttons = {};

    callMe[n_] := Module[{}, MessageDialog[choices[[n]]]];

    test[] := Module[{}, buttons = {};

       Scan[With[{t = Length@buttons + 1}, 
          AppendTo[buttons, Button[#, callMe[t]]]] &, choices];

       Return@buttons;

    ];

    test[]